# Duplicate Values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using this query and have used the Select Distinct code to enusre no duplicates are pulled from the database.

However on my QTD colum the number is sometimes X2 the proper amount?

This is probably an error with the server or would my query be incorrect?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad.eid, MAX(u1.email) as ops,MAX(u2.email) as rep,
    (SUM(ad.cost)) as qtd_spend,
    Sum(case when day < current_date AND day >='2015-01-01' then cost else 0 end) as MTD,
    AVG(case when day < current_date AND day >= current_date-7 then cost else null end) as weekly_spend
    FROM adcube as ad
    inner JOIN advertisables as a on ad.eid = a.eid
    LEFT JOIN organizations as o on o.id = a.id 
    LEFT outer JOIN users as u1 on o.ops_organization_id = u1.organization_id
    LEFT outer JOIN users as u2 on o.sales_organization_id = u2.organization_id
    WHERE day >='2015-01-01' and day < current_date 
    GROUP BY eid
```

Comment: Are you aware that `distinct` operates on **all**?  Please show us some sample data, the current output and the expected output based on that sample data (ideally as a http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: GROUP BY eid makes the DISTINCT redundant. (In most cases you use either DISTINCT or GROUP BY - not both.)

Comment: When I remove the group by it returns the following error;

column "ad.eid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: In additions to the observations made above, I suspect one of your `Left join` is cause the doubling of the `QTD` amount. I would eliminate each `Left Join` to check which one causes it to double and go from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have `GROUP BY` if you have aggregate functions (such as SUM or MAX).

What is likely the problem is in you JOINs.

I am not familiar with your data structure, but I am assuming that in your advertisables table, it contains (or CAN contain) more than one entry of the same "eid" - is this correct? Or do you have a constraint?

If this is correct, then when you join *even if* you have only ONE entry in the "adcube" table, once it JOINs with the multiple entries in the "advertisables" table then it pulls up TWO records (or however many match) and then the aggregate results at the select level of the statement then sum BOTH (or more) columsn.

So you should take the duplicates out of hte joining tables or factor that into account.

**EDIT:**

Ok, well glad to know that is the problem. You will not fix it by `INNER JOINING` either. You will have to do an inline select statement.

The best way to solve this, from what I understand you are trying to do, is do the following:

```
SELECT ad.eid
     , (
         select max(u1.email)
    from JOIN advertisables as a 
         LEFT JOIN organizations as o on o.id = a.id 
         LEFT outer JOIN users as u1 on o.ops_organization_id = u1.organization_id
         LEFT outer JOIN users as u2 on o.sales_organization_id = u2.organization_id
     where a.eid = ad.eid
       ) as ops
     , (
         select max(u2.email)
    from JOIN advertisables as a 
         LEFT JOIN organizations as o on o.id = a.id 
         LEFT outer JOIN users as u1 on o.ops_organization_id = u1.organization_id
         LEFT outer JOIN users as u2 on o.sales_organization_id = u2.organization_id
     where a.eid = ad.eid
       ) as rep
     , (SUM(ad.cost)) as qtd_spend
     , Sum(case when day < current_date AND day >='2015-01-01' then cost else 0 end) as MTD
     , AVG(case when day < current_date AND day >= current_date-7 then cost else null end) as weekly_spend
FROM adcube as ad
    WHERE day >='2015-01-01' and day < current_date 
    GROUP BY eid
```

Comment: Thats correct the advertisable table can contain multiples. I'll change the join on the Advertisables table to a inner join and see if it fixes the issue.